# WildFly9 using XA datasource with latest MySQL drivers, unable to set DefaultFetchSize

Tags: mysql, wildfly, xa

After updating mysql drivers to version `6.0.4` in my WildFly instance it looks like I'm not able to set `DefaultFetchSize` anymore doing the following:

`<xa-datasource-property name="DefaultFetchSize" />`

After doing a quick look at the new xa datasource class the getters/setters seems to have simply vanished. So, how do I set this property now, if it vanished from the datasource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the property is simply missing in the new driver. After rolling back to latest 5.1 everything works fine.